# Unix Shell Scripting - Bug in command

Tags: linux, shell, unix

This is my Unix Assignment where I need to write a script which shows today's date in calender and here's my code and the output. My professor gave me grade with feedback saying "fix the command there is a bug in it". I can't seem to figure out the bug. Any help will be great!

command is $c5/n*/4*/s*/today

Where those are just some directories and today is the name of my file. When I type in that command I see what I want to see which is output of my script, then how can there be a bug in my command.

```
#!/usr/dt/bin/dtksh

date
if [ $# -ge 1 ] ; then
exec $HOME/bin/cal $*
fi
#highlight today on this months calendar

daynumber=`date +%d`
#tput gets terminal specific characters, e.g. clear
rmso=`tput rmso` # get the chars for reverse video for this
smso=`tput smso` # terminal using tput

if [ $daynumber -lt 10 ] ; then
daynumber=" `echo $daynumber | sed 's/^0//`"
# daynumber=" `echo $daynumber | cut -c 2`"
fi

if cal | grep "$daynumber\$" > /dev/null; then
cal | sed "2,$ s/$daynumber/$smso$daynumber$rmso /"
else
cal | sed "2,$ s/$daynumber /$smso$daynumber$rmso /"
fi
```

Output... 30 will be highlighted since that is today's date.

```
Sun Mar 30 14:22:31 CDT 2014
   March 2014
 S  M Tu  W Th  F  S
                   1
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22
23 24 25 26 27 28 29
**30** 31
```

Comment: Not just one bug. `$*` and `"$@"` are very different things, and you almost certainly want the latter.

Comment: ...also, there are much more efficient ways to kill leading zeros. `daynumber=${daynumber%0}` is much, **much** faster than forking, starting a pipeline, waiting for it to exit, etc.

Comment: You are missing a single quote in the `daynumber=...sed...` line.

Comment: He actually said there is bug in your command. Not my script

Comment: Why don't you ask *him* what he means?

Comment: A script becomes a command when you make it executable — at least, that's one way of looking at it.  Are you sure the terms aren't simply interchangeable.  And if he said 'your command', which command does he mean if it is not the script that is implementing the command?

Comment: Try this: `cal | od -c` and see how cal highlights today.

Comment: You don't want `%d` -- read the date man page to see which %-sequence you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is "write a script which shows today's date in calender "

If I understand correctly, you are building a "fork" of cal. 
Your script doesn't use any of input from cmdline :

```
if [ $# -ge 1 ] ; then
exec $HOME/bin/cal $*
fi
```

=> remove that block.

It uses this as an input for the day of today ( which is what you want) :

```
daynumber=`date +%d`
```

Bonus : cal can highlight day by default, check cal manpage.

> turn off highlighting ( -h)

Comment: Anyway Charles Duffy is right, $* is a bad idea. Check advanced bash guide. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html
see Inconsistent $* and $@ behavior